# Calling local file bash-profile.rc from .bash_profile

Tags: bash

I want to call a local file `bash-profile.rc` for setting environment variables for Tex Live.  How can I call and execute the commands in `bash-profile.rc` from `.bash_profile`?

Comment: put something like `. ~/bash-profile.rc` in your .bash_profile

Comment: I see you source it.  Would I need `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning?

Comment: No need, but, is the file written in bash?

Comment: `bash-profile.rc` has `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.

Comment: all's good then

Comment: Yes, all good with profile.